# Isekai manga where the MC levels up young, accidentally gets engaged and becomes nobility

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Looking for an op mc isekai where he levels up young.  Gets taken to the capital.  Rescues the young princess and duchess.  Accidentally gets engaged.  Becomes himself nobility.  Makes glassware and mounts a dragon in the front hall for his first party.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. If there are any other details you happen to remember please [edit] them in. Have a look at our checklists: [_how to ask a good story-id question_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335), and [_how to ask a good (anime/manga) story-id question_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874)

Comment: How is he mounting said dragon?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *[Tensei Kizoku No Isekai Boukenroku ~ Jichou Wo Shiranai Kamigami No Shito](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Tensei_Kizoku_no_Isekai_Boukenroku:_Jichou_wo_Shiranai_Kamigami_no_Shito)* (*Chronicles of an Aristocrat Reborn in Another World: The Apostle of the Gods Who Know No Self-Restraint*).

> Teenager Shiinya Kazuya died while saving young girls from an
> attacker, only to find himself reincarnated into a world of swords and
> magic. It was a dream come true! Though he remembers his life and
> knowledge of Earth, he is now Cain von Silford, the third son of an
> aristocrat. Being granted the protection of the gods on his fifth
> birthday turned out to be too much of a good thing for Cain.
>
> His stats and boosts are so powerful, he must hide his real abilities
> to climb the ranks of society as he descends into the darkest
> dungeons. The ultimate isekai adventure begins as a teen-turned-child
> is trapped in a beautiful kingdom he didn't create, but might one day
> rule!
>
> [image]

Please take a look, confirm and good luck.